# Pytest running unittest exit with core dump

Tags: pytest, python-unittest

So far we have used python unittest framework. Now we would like to start using pytest due to the following reasons:

1. junit xml report for jenkins
2. Parallel execution with pytest-xdist

Our existing testing framework includes cases were several test classes are derived from single class which in place is the one derived from `unittest.TestCase` in this way they share the same `setUp/tearDown`. In pytest I believe it is done with fixture.

When we attempt to run our tests folder with pytest, in case the classes are directly derived from `unittest.TestCase` tests are running fine. However, if the classes are derived from our class (as shown below) pytest crash with Abort(core dump).

```
class l2_acl_base(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.device_name = '/dev/testdev'
        self.create_system_setup()
        self.create_packets()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.device.tearDown()

class acl_force_destination(l2_acl_base):
    def test_acl_force_destination(self):
```

Comment: Please show the full error stack trace.

Comment: Happened to me too, the error is not a pythonic exception:
```python
[1]    1173852 IOT instruction (core dumped)  pytest 
```

Answer (score -3):

I was able to trace it back to ENV issue and the problem is not related to pytest
Consider the case close.

Comment: Any details?  I'm having the same problem, also due to environment variables, but I don't know which or why.